# How to change world in blender 2.79?

Tags: python, world

I created two materials for world, World and WorldMask. How to change world from World to WorldMask using python script?

Comment: I've found a solution: bpy.context.scene.world = bpy.data.worlds['WorldMask']

Comment: Please write this in the answer field and to add it as an answer. You can always answer your own question, if you find a solution. This will be helpful for others in the future who find your Q.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution `bpy.context.scene.world = bpy.data.worlds['WorldMask']`